# Constructor Chaining, did I do it right?

Tags: c#, constructor, chaining

I am learning about constructor chaining in an effort to reduce redundant code and was just wondering if I have a decent grasp and did it right.  Do I need this.Name = restaurantName in the third constructor as well? Here is the code:

```
 public Restaurant()
    {
        this.Name = DefaultName;
        this.Chain = null;
        this.SeatingCapacity = MinSeats;
        this.Smoking = false;
        this.LastMonthSales = MinSales;
        this.LastMonthCosts = MinCosts;
        this.OpenDays = new List<DayOfWeek>();
    }

    public Restaurant(string restaurantName)
        :this()
    {
        this.Name = restaurantName;            
    }

    public Restaurant(string restaurantName, int capacity)
        :this(restaurantName)
    {            
        this.SeatingCapacity = capacity;            
    }
```

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: Yup. And no you do not need to set `restaurantName` in your third constructor, as it will be set in the second.

Comment: Yes, it's by far correct approach. BTW, it's also known as `constructor initializer`

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify this a bit by parameterizing the main constructor, then passing in defaults for the other overloads:

```
public Restaurant(string restaurantName, int capacity)
{
    this.Name = restaurantName;
    this.Chain = null;
    this.SeatingCapacity = capacity;
    this.Smoking = false;
    this.LastMonthSales = MinSales;
    this.LastMonthCosts = MinCosts;
    this.OpenDays = new List<DayOfWeek>();
}

public Restaurant(string restaurantName) : this(restaurantName, MinSeats)
{}

public Restaurant() : this(DefaultName)
{}
```